# How to enable ds-rollback-attribute in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

Ember has method `rollbackAttribute()` which is very similar to the default method `rollbackAttributes()`. The difference is `rollbackAttribute()` can be used to rollback ONLY specific model attribute.
By default this method is not available and to use it you need to enable `ds-rollback-attribute` and run the canary build as written here: https://docs.w3cub.com/ember/classes/ds.model/methods/#rollbackAttribute

Where can I enable the `ds-rollback-attribute` and how can I ran the `canary build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the implementation of the `rollbackAttribute()` is quite simple.
We can create our own method and extract it into the `service`.

`app/services/rollback-attribute.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  rollback(model, attribute) {
    const changedAttributes = model.changedAttributes();
    if (changedAttributes[attribute]) {
      model.set(attribute, changedAttributes[attribute][0]);
    }
  }
});
```

After creating this service you can use it for example in the `route.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import service from 'ember-service/inject';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  rollbackAttribute: service('rollback-attribute'),

  _rollbackAttribute(model, attribute) {
    this.get('rollbackAttribute').rollback(model, key);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are looking at non-official and outdated API docs. The API docs for Ember Data are hosted here: https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release

The `rollbackAttribute()` method is not documented anymore for the latest release, which is `3.13` at the time writing this. It was [last documented for `3.1`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttribute?anchor=rollbackAttribute). I think it was removed as a stale feature flag in this PR: [[FEAT] remove all stale feature flags #5384](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/5384)